# Make a Checkbox none clickable ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table which renders some data from the Model and Controller. I have the table working, however, is there a way that I can stop the checkboxes in the table being clicked.

My code is:

```
<tbody>
                @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Writers.Count(); i++)
                {
                <tr data-id="@Model.Writers[i].WriterId"
                    data-name="@Model.Writers[i].FirstName@Model.Writers[i].LastName"
                    data-membership="@Model.Writers[i].Membership"
                    data-capipinumber="@Model.Writers[i].CaeIpiNumber"
                    data-share="@Model.Writers[i].Share"
                    date-righttocollect="@Model.Writers[i].RightToCollect">

                    <td>@Model.Writers[i].FirstName @Model.Writers[i].LastName</td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@Model.Writers[i].Membership</td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">@Model.Writers[i].CaeIpiNumber</td>
                    <td>@Model.Writers[i].Share</td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Writers[i].RightToCollect, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                tableRowIndex++;
}
            </tbody>
```

I am just a little unsure whether it is possible to make the checkboxes no clickable, so they are locked in a way.

Comment: Why do you manually set the `checked` attribute value? The checkbox state is defined by result of expression, that you passed as first argument of the [helper method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @Alexander It is some fake data that I have in my controller to see whether its pulling the data from the model. I have removed all of that and gone back to the basics and it renders the checkbox input. Is there a way that I can lock it?

Comment: Do you mean [`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) attribute?

Comment: Or do you want to checkbox will be checked by default?

Comment: @Alexander the disabled option is okay, but I would like it so that you cant click the checkboxes. So they are locked.

Comment: I don't understand you. It is not posdible to change state of `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">`, it is locked. See [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios) from the Bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I used the HTML disabled attribute like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Writers[i].RightToCollect, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

It disabled all the checked and unchecked checkboxes, so you can't click on them, which is exactly what I was looking for.